# how to get all text of an p tag except last with htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

i have a html like that is one p tag (number 10) in a div with class "fine"

```
 <p>
    first para.
    <br/>
    second para.
<br/>
    <br/>
    nine para .
    ...
    <br/>
    last para.

    </p>
```

i want to get all text except last paragraph :
first para.
second para.
 nine para .
    ...

```
HtmlNode item = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='fine']/p[10]//text()");
```

this code just get :
first para.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, `SelectSingleNode()` only return single node. In case of multiple nodes matched by the XPath parameter, it returns only the first one.

You're supposed to use `SelectNodes()` instead, and add a predicate `[position() < last()]` to exclude the last text node :

```
string query = "//div[@class='fine']/p[10]//text()[position() < last()]";
HtmlNode items = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(query);
```

Comment: thanks it works for this example  , but when i use in my query it has errror:

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.